# How do I connect to a c# chat server on ec2

Tags: networking, tcp, amazon-ec2, udp

I created a chat server with c#. I can run this all on localhost and the client can connect to the server.

I set up an Amazon EC2 cloud service. I set up the server on there and started it. I cannot connect to the server running in my ec2 instance from my client running on my home computer.

I set up an elastic IP address. I then assigned it to the instance that's running the server.

I set up the security group as follows:

[image]

[image]

I can now ping my server, but my client still cannot connect to the server. 
(I realize opening up the security group this much is dangerous, but this is for a school project so I only need it to run 5 minutes at a time)

What am I missing? How can I get my client to connect to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your source code for the TcpListener binding. It should listen to all IP addresses rather than the localhost, which is a common mistake. Use IPAddress.Any.

Comment: That was one problem, but its still not connecting. Checked firewall settings too with no luck

Comment: It was the firewall on the EC2 VM (Win 2008 server) that was blocking my connections. Thanks again for the help!