# Host a web application on Amazon EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2

I'm working on some software which communicates via a Web interface.  the server software is written in C#, and I was hoping to host the server software on an amazon ec2 instance.  I am now running the software and while I can get a response from the server itself (by pointing a browser at http:// localhost:8080), I can't seem to get a corresponding response from any other computer, either by using http://[ip address]:8080 or http://[aws machine name]:8080.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. By default all ports except RDC are disabled in EC2. You have to manually enable them via the EC2 control panel. Additionally, I couldn't get anything to connect to the server because the windows firewall on the server blocked everything by default. I also set up elastic IPs, not sure if it was required, I kind of just poked it with a stick until it worked.

Comment: Here was my question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929570/how-do-i-connect-to-a-c-sharp-chat-server-on-ec2 You can see from the screenshots what I mean by enabling the ports in EC2 control panel